# Object is possibly 'undefined'. TS2532 /

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Answered

So I`m importing 2 arrays of objects from folder api , then I create variable List where each object  - todosFromServer -    contains sub object  - usersFromServer - .
Here is interface of combined List object

```
export interface List {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  completed: boolean;
  userId: number;
  user: {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    username: string;
    email: string;
  };
}
```

Here is example from usersFromServer object

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Leanne Graham',
    username: 'Bret',
    email: 'Sincere@april.biz',
},
```

Here is example from todosFromServer

```
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'delectus aut autem',
    completed: true,
    userId: 1,
  },
```

I created function handleSubmit() for form submits,  where after some primitive validation in IF() statement I create new Object newUser with type List and then I mutate list array of objects adding newUser.

QUESTUIN PART  But , terminal , on property userId writes that Object is possibly 'undefined'.
I tried inside interface to set   userId?: number | undefined;
but it doen`t change anything , plus I know that it will never be undefined as result of find method.

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import './App.scss';

import usersFromServer from './api/users';
import todosFromServer from './api/todos';
import { List } from './type/List';

import { TodoList } from './components/TodoList/TodoList';

let list: List[] = [...todosFromServer].map(todo => {
  const user = [...usersFromServer].find(person => person.id === todo.userId);

  return { ...todo, user };
});

export const App:React.FC = () => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState<string>('');
  const [user, setUser] = useState<string>('Please choose a user');
  const [errorUser, setErrorUser] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [errorTitle, setErrorTitle] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>):void => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const sortedArray = [...list].sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
    const id = sortedArray[sortedArray.length - 1].id + 1;

    if (title === '' || user === 'Please choose a user') {
      if (title === '') {
        setErrorTitle(true);
      }

      if (user === 'Please choose a user') {
        setErrorUser(true);
      }

      return;
    }

    const newUser: List = {
      id,
      title,
      completed: false,
      user: usersFromServer
        .find(person => person.name === user),
      userId: usersFromServer
        .find(person => person.name === user).id,
    };

    list = [...list, newUser];

    setTitle('');
    setUser('Please choose a user');
  };
```

Will be glad for any explanation of what I`m doing wrong.

problem is inside handleSubmit() when I define and assign newUser object, here is condensed version of function

```
const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>):void => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const sortedArray = [...list].sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
    const id = sortedArray[sortedArray.length - 1].id + 1;

    const newUser: List = {
      id,
      title,
      completed: false,
      user: usersFromServer
        .find(person => person.name === user),
      userId: usersFromServer
        .find(person => person.name === user).id,
    };

    list = [...list, newUser];
  };
```

Comment: Hi, where exactly are you getting the error (I see `userId` used in a couple places)? Can you create a [mre]?

Comment: `.find` returns object or undefined, that's why you getting the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this error on the access to `.id` when you set `userId` for `newUser` in `handleSubmit`, this access will fail when there is no match. In order to account for this you can use [optional chaining (?.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

So the lookup would look like this: `usersFromServer.find(person => person.name === user)?.id`

You would need to set both the `user` and `userId` property to support the optional value `undefined` in order to avoid TypeScript errors as well.

Answer (score 0):

So , inside of the handleSubmit() function , during newUser deaclaration and assignement I specified that user property can be either User object or null (same in interface definition) ,
and userId is optional;

```
const newUser: List = {
      id,
      title,
      completed: false,
      user: usersFromServer
        .find(person => person.name === user) || null,
      userId: usersFromServer
        .find(person => person.name === user)?.id,
    };
```

in type folder List interface

```
export interface List {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  completed: boolean;
  userId?: number;
  user: User | null;
}
```

when rendering .user I have to check that it is truish value,

Thanks to everebody who left comments and answer, that was super helpful.